# Multiple case conditions are executed And giving error

Tags: oracle, case

I am using the following query

```
SELECT d.mon,
CASE
WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN d.DRR = '80+' THEN 9999 ELSE TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,1,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') - 1)) END) = 9999 THEN '80+'
WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN d.DRR = 'CURR' THEN 0 ELSE TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,1,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') - 1)) END) = 0 THEN 'CURR'
ELSE(
 TO_CHAR(max(TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,1,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') - 1)))) || '-' ||
 TO_CHAR(MAX( TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') +1)) ))))
END
AS bill
FROM table d
GROUP BY d.mon
ORDER BY d.mon
```

but it is giving me invalid number.I have the following dataset:

| mon | DRR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80+ |
| 1 | 1-30 |

it should result in :

| mon | DRR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80+ |

it isn't working until I add the following condition:

```
  TO_CHAR(MAX(CASE WHEN d.DRR = 'CURR' THEN 0 WHEN d.DRR = '80+' THEN 1 ELSE TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') +1)) END))
```

why I need to add this condition even when it meets the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you got *invalid number* error. That's because you're trying to apply `to_number` function to result of this `substr`:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     table1 (mon, drr)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, '80+' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 1, '1-30' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT SUBSTR (d.DRR, INSTR (d.DRR, '-') + 1)    --> this
  8    FROM table1 d;

SUBS
----
80+            --> this is where TO_NUMBER fails
30

SQL>
```

---

What is that query supposed to do? Conditions look kind of *complicated*. Do you need to use the `max` function? If so, why? You're comparing two values, so perhaps you'd just have to use `greatest`? Could you explain - in plain English - what problem you're trying to solve? Which rules have to be applied to *source* data to get *target* data? Maybe your query can be (significantly?) simplified.

Comment: The OP is not adding 1 to the `SUBSTR` value, they are adding 1 to the `INSTR` value which is a number (and so are you in the code you posted) so the first part of your answer is wrong. The rest of the "answer" should be comments on the question as it does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @MT0, part of OP's code I'm talking about is their 3rd line which says `... ELSE TO_NUMBER(substr(d.DRR,1,INSTR(d.DRR, '-') - 1)) END)` and that SUBSTR returns "80+" and applying TO_NUMBER to "80+" raises INVALID NUMBER error. Unless I'm wrong, the first part of my answer isn't wrong. As of the second part of that "answer", yes - should've been a comment, but I was probably lazy to do two things instead of only one.

Comment: You have missed the main point of the OP's question which is that `CASE` expressions should shortcut the logic so if either of the first 2 `WHEN` clauses are matched then the OP expects the third `WHEN` clause should not be evaluated and the exception should never be raised.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression uses short-circuit logic so that if the first `WHEN` expression matches then subsequent `WHEN` or `ELSE` clauses will not be evaluated.

However, when you are using aggregation functions it is not efficient to parse the entire result set to evaluate the aggregations in the first `WHEN` clause and then re-parse the entire result set to evaluate the second `WHEN` clause and so-on for each clause of the `CASE` expression; instead, the SQL engine will parse the result set once and calculate the value of all the aggregations and then will apply the `CASE` expression using the results of the aggregation which means that all the rows are going to be evaluated for all the aggregations.

If you try without the aggregation:

```sql
SELECT mon,
       CASE
       WHEN CASE WHEN drr = '80+' THEN 1 END = 1
       THEN '80+'
       WHEN CASE WHEN drr = 'CURR' THEN 1 END = 1
       THEN 'CURR'
       ELSE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, 1, INSTR(drr, '-') - 1))
            || '-'
            || TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, INSTR(drr, '-') + 1))
       END AS bill
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY mon;
```

Then the query successfully completes and the short-circuit logic is applied so that the `ELSE` clause is not evaluated when either of the `WHEN` clauses is matched. However, with aggregation, it does not work.

If you want to fix it then you need to guard against strings that do not match the `x-y` pattern; you can either:

Use regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT mon,
       CASE
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = '80+' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN '80+'
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = 'CURR' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN 'CURR'
       ELSE MAX(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(drr, '^(\d+)-(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)))
            || '-'
            || MAX(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(drr, '^(\d+)-(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)))
       END AS bill
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY mon
ORDER BY mon;
```

or using `INSTR` to check that there is a hyphen character in the string:

```sql
SELECT mon,
       CASE
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = '80+' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN '80+'
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = 'CURR' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN 'CURR'
       ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN INSTR(drr, '-') > 0 THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, 1, INSTR(drr, '-') - 1)) END)
            || '-'
            || MAX(CASE WHEN INSTR(drr, '-') > 0 THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, INSTR(drr, '-') + 1)) END)
       END AS bill
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY mon
ORDER BY mon;
```

Or filter out the previous matches:

```sql
SELECT mon,
       CASE
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = '80+' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN '80+'
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN drr = 'CURR' THEN 1 END) = 1
       THEN 'CURR'
       ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN drr NOT IN ('80+', 'CURR') THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, 1, INSTR(drr, '-') - 1)) END)
            || '-'
            || MAX(CASE WHEN drr NOT IN ('80+', 'CURR') THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(drr, INSTR(drr, '-') + 1)) END)
       END AS bill
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY mon
ORDER BY mon;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (mon, DRR) AS
  SELECT 1, '80+'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-30' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| MON | BILL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80+ |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6weEzaS6)